# getExternalFilesDir(null) returns null in Espresso tests

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-external-storage, android-instrumentation, scoped-storage

I'm trying to access `getExternalFilesDir(null)` from an Espresso test during the execution of a `@BeforeClass` method to set up some app files before starting tests.

I'm trying to access it like this:
`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.getExternalFilesDir(null)`

`Environment.getExternalStorageState()` returns `"mounted"`, yet `getExternalFilesDir(null)` returns null in the above call, contrary to the documentation which states it would only return null if storage wasn't mounted.

Interestingly enough, `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.filesDir` does return a value, but it returns a non-existent folder which is under a test package instead of the app's actual package.

How can I access and write to app's scoped storage when setting up an Espresso test?

Comment: do you have write/read external storage permissions in code and in your device?

Comment: Yes, but even if I didn't, the documentation clearly states permissions are not required on 4.4+ devices for getExternalFilesDir()

Comment: Maybe try `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)` ?

Comment: App context is null.

Comment: @Sharp in your test file, have you added test rule using `GrantPermissionRule.grant()` for Read External Storage Permission?

Comment: No, because permissions are not required for that call. However, I did try also with the rule, and it's still null as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context` gives you the context for the test APK.
`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext` gives you the context for the APK under test.

If the directory has not yet been created, `getExternalFilesDir` might return `null` the first time, **so you may have to call it twice.**

With `targetSdk=30` on an API 30 emulator, this:

```kotlin
    companion object {
        @BeforeClass @JvmStatic
        fun beforeClass() {
            val targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
            Log.d("storage", targetContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString())
            Log.d("storage", targetContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString())
        }
    }
```

Will print this on first install/run:

```
D/storage: null
D/storage: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/files
```

and this on the second run:

```
D/storage: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/files
D/storage: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/files
```

More on behavior with `targetSdk=30`:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#migrate-legacy-storage

Comment: Perfect! I had no idea about the context vs targetContext difference, but it now makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: My problem is fixed - however one more thing, I actually cannot reproduce the part with the first call being null. Now that I use it with targetContext, it always returns a non-null value, even when I do a clean install and target 30. I'm using a real device though.